# Alinhar DIV dinamicamente como um vitral

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde

Estou num projeto pessoal e uma das minhas inspirações é o layout do Google Keep, onde as divs se alinham e se encaixam como se estivessem formando um vitral. Fiz alguns testes alinhando as divs para esquerda (float: left), mas as divs sempre respeitam a altura do final da maior div que já está na tela, e aí fica um espaço em branco em alguns lugares.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer esse tipo de alinhamento? Para uma ideia melhor do que eu estou falando, deem uma olhada nessa imagem: http://tiredopapel.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Google_Keep_Web_Update-630x484.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiz um exemplo no [jsFddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wpwa8hL/1/) pra vc entender o funcionamento, mas também vou colocar aqui:

Basicamente, você controla as colunas com as tags `column-count` e `column-gap` do CSS.

```css
.geral{padding: 5px;height: 390px;}
.collum{   
-webkit-column-count: 5;
-webkit-column-gap: 0px;
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
 -moz-column-count: 5;
-moz-column-gap: 5px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
column-count: 5;
column-gap: 0px;
column-fill: auto;}

.quadrado{width: 100px; height: 150px; background: orange; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;    display: inline-block;
}
.um{height: 130px}
.dois{height: 180px}
.tres{height: 120px}
.quatro{height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="geral">
  <div class="collum">
      <div class="quadrado"></div>
      <div class="quadrado um"></div>
      <div class="quadrado dois"></div>
      <div class="quadrado"></div>
      <div class="quadrado"></div>
      <div class="quadrado tres"></div>
      <div class="quadrado"></div>
      <div class="quadrado quatro"></div>
      <div class="quadrado"></div>
      <div class="quadrado"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, entendi
Fiz uns testes aqui e se aproximou muito do que eu quero, vou seguir por aí mesmo
Obrigado David Damasceno

Comment: Tranquilo cara, se estiver de acordo com o que vc queria, por favor marque a resposta como aceita.